# One Time Access URL after purchasing subscription

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, permalinks, urls, membership

Here's the scenario:
A client is selling a product which allows for ONE use of a Web App. The Web App has a simple URL, like **www.company.com/app/the-awesome-tool** (it's not publicly accessible)
I've been thinking on how to resolve this but can't wrap my head around it... the only thing I can think of is that after the purchase, the client is sent a UNIQUE URL that forwards him or her to [www.company.com/app/the-awesome-tool](http://www.company.com/app/the-awesome-tool) (with masked URL), which then expires after accessing it.
How can I achieve this? We have **MemberPress** installed, and can also install **WooCommerc** to resolve this.
Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be creating a unique token upon purchasing a subscription/product.

1. Save to token somewhere in database.
2. Present the URL to the app passing the token as a GET variable. For eample, `www.company.com/app/the-awesome-tool/?token=jvp2HBst5V7iHQeE2twq`
3. When accessed, check is the token is there at the database, if not restrict access.
4. Delete the token from database if the access was granted.

This could be extended by comparing user ID, order id etc.